# How to extract attributes of polygons at specific points into new point layer in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection, attribute-joins, grids-graticules

I am not very practiced in PostGIS. However, my volume of data forces me to use it. I have a large polygon layer containing several million polygons and a grid layer that has a point every 10 meters within the bounding box of the polygon layer (see picture). I now want to extract the attributes of the underlying polygon at each point into a new point layer. It should be an outer join where the point id from the original grid and all attributes from my polygon shapefile are added to the resulting point layer. I achieved this in R with a small test data set pretty easily and now need a PostGIS equivalent. My attempts so far have failed.

R version for little data set:

```
polygons <- st_read("polygons.shp")

grid <- st_read("grid.shp")

result <- st_intersection(polygons, grid)
```

My attempt so far in PostGIS which has failed:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS result;

CREATE TABLE result AS
 SELECT a.geom AS ageom, b.geom AS bgeom,
        ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) As intersect_ab
 FROM polygons a 
   INNER JOIN grid b ON ST_Intersection(a,b)
 WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom);
```

[image]

Comment: Join on ST_Intersects (the boolean condition) versus ST_Intersection (the result of the geometric intersection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple query to do this is:

```
SELECT pt.id, poly.*
  FROM grid pt
  JOIN polygons poly ON ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pt.geom);
```

One caveat: this will return multiple records if a point lies in multiple polygons. To ensure only a single record is returned per point, and also to include points which do not lie in any polygon, use:

```
SELECT pt.id, poly.*
  FROM grid pt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT * FROM polygons poly 
       WHERE ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pt.geom) LIMIT 1) AS poly ON true;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I have no interest in keeping the points that don't lie in a polygon. How can I adjust the function to leave them out?

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`) instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`